# Show Active Cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I know this is way easier than I am making it, but I am a beginner. The following code will show the current cell selection in excel. What I need is the exact same code, but for Google Sheets:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("A1").Value = ActiveCell.Address
End Sub
```

Here is what I put in Google Script:

```
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
 var currentCell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
```

But it does not seem to work, and I know I am missing something.

Comment: If you want a1Notation, you can retrieve it by ``currentCell.getA1Notation()``. If you want to put it to "A1", you can do it by ``sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(currentCell.getA1Notation())``. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getA1Notation()

Comment: Removed the the [tag:excel] because the question doesn't involve an interaction with that application. There isn't enough context, please add more details like if you are working on a bounded to spreadsheet project, how are you running the referred [tag:google-apps-script] code lines, the execution transcript and error that you got. Add a [mcve].